# OpportunityContactRole ContactID issue

Tags: apex, opportunitycontactrole

This is for contactId field of opportunityContactRole. We are trying to assign a person account to contactID as there is no contact for the custom object Assignee, it has only PersonAccount field. All the contacts are pointed/diverted to PersonAccounts.

How to get the contactID of this OpportunityContactRole when an Attendee(Custom object) is created under an opportunity.

Any help in this matter is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A person account has a contactId that's accessed via `account.contactId`. For more on this, see the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf).